# Inflector::humanize($key) converts Date of joining TO Date Of Joining

Tags: php, cakephp

I have a Form and i am submitting them like using

```
function submit($formid = null, $fillerid = null){
    $this->data['Result']['form_id'] = $formid;
    $this->data['Result']['submitter_id'] = $fillerid;
    $this->data['Result']['submitter'] = $this->Session->read('filler');
    echo "submitter: " . $this->Session->read('filler');
    $results = $this->Form->hasResults($this->data);
    //echo http_build_query($_POST);

    if(empty($results)){
        foreach($_POST as $key => $value):
            if(is_array($value)){
                $value = implode('', $_POST[$key]);
                $this->data['Result']['value'] = $value;
            }else{
                $this->data['Result']['value'] = $value;
            }
            $this->data['Result']['form_id'] = $formid;
            $this->data['Result']['submitter_id'] = $fillerid;
            $this->data['Result']['label'] = Inflector::humanize($key);

            $this->data['Result']['submitter'] = $this->Session->read('filler');
            $this->Form->submitForm($this->data);
        endforeach;

        $this->Session->setFlash('Your entry has been submitted.');
    }
}
```

I am having A fORM LIKE

```
  <form method="post" action="/FormBuilder/index.php/forms/submit/1/4" id="ResultSubmit"> 

  <div class="input text"><label for="1">Firstname</label><input type="text" value="" style="width: 300px;" id="1" name="Firstname"/></div>  <br/>




  <div class="input text"><label for="2">Last Name</label><input type="text" value="" style="width: 300px;" id="2" name="Last Name"/></div>  <br/>




  <div class="input text"><label for="3">Age</label><input type="text" value="" style="width: 200px;" id="3" name="Age"/></div>  <br/>
       <center>  <span id="errmsg3"/> </center>



  <div class="input textarea"><label for="4">Address</label><textarea style="height: 300px;" id="4" rows="6" cols="30" name="Address"/></div>  <br/>



  <div class="input text"><label for="5">Date Of Joining</label><input type="text" value="" style="width: 300px;" id="5" name="Date of joining"/></div><br/>


  <div class="input text"><label for="6">Email - Id</label><input type="text" value="" style="width: 300px;" id="6" name="Email - id"/></div>  <br/>




  <div class="input text">
<label for="7">Personal Number</label><input type="text" value="" maxlength="3" style="width: 30px;" id="7" name="Personal Number[]"/><input type="text" value="" style="width: 30px;" maxlength="3" id="7-1" name="Personal Number[]"/><input type="text" value="" style="width: 70px;" maxlength="4" id="7-2" name="Personal Number[]"/></div>

 <span id="errmsg7"/> 
  <br/>




  <div class="input select"><label for="8">Gender</label><select id="8" name="Gender">
```

MaleFemale

```
  <div class="input text"><label for="9">Official Number</label><input type="text" value="" style="width: 200px;" id="9" name="Official Number"/></div><br/>


     <div class="input select"><label for="10">Experience</label><select id="10" name="Experience">
    <option value="Fresher">Fresher</option><option yrs="" 5="" value="Below">Below 5 Yrs</option><option yrs="" 10="" value="Above">Above 10 yrs</option></select></div><br/>
```

actually My input has the names as

- Firstname
- Last Name
- Age
- Address
- Date of joining
- Email - id
- Personal Number
- Gender
- Official Number

But when i use Inflector::humanize($key) for saving the names which has white space characters they have converted into like Date Of Joining i.e.., O and J becomes Capital letters... But i need to save them as such as Date of joining..
How to do so???

Answer (score 0):

You have to write your own method to accomplish that. If you want to capitalize the first character of the string, you could take the code of Inflector::humanize() and replace ucwords() with ucfirst():

```
function humanize($lowerCaseAndUnderscoredWord) {  
    return ucfirst(str_replace("_", " ", $lowerCaseAndUnderscoredWord));  
}
```

Comment: Where will be the actual humanize method()? I mean the location

Comment: You would place this method into a custom class, probably in the vendors folder.